# How do I force a UIImageView and its subviews to redraw in a new context?

Tags: iphone, graphics, uiimageview

kSBCanvas is a SBCanvas, which is a subclass of UIImageView.  It has a few UIImageView subviews.  It all renders great to the iPhone screen.

I need composite the kSBCanvas and its subviews to an imageview that I want to write to disk.

I do the following:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(kSBCanvas.bounds.size);
 [kSBCanvas drawRect: [kSBCanvas bounds]];

 UIImage *theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

then get a PNG representation and write it to disk.

The kSBCanvas renders, but not the subview images.  I checked, and kBCanvas has subviews.  Do I have to call drawRect on the subviews explicitly?  Easy enough, but it does not seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(kSBCanvas.bounds.size);
{
    [kSBCanvas.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Rendering the layer should also render all the subviews.

Comment: Seems right, but the compiler says "no 'renderInContext:' method found?  kSBCanvas is absolutely an object that's a subclass of UIImageView. I know this is simple.  What's going on?  Also, I can't use theImage if it's bracked as shown above.  No big deal.

Comment: You will need to `#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: Just remove the brackets. It is my own weird style.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you so much.  It's confusing that the header has to be added, but the solution is exactly what I needed.